# Chrome Developer Tools -Accessibility

Tags: accessibility, chrome

The Accessibility tab in Chrome developer tools run on a input without a label compiles to:

- aria-labelledby: Not specified
- aria-label: Not specified
- **From label: Not specified**
- placeholder: Not specified
- aria-placeholder: Not specified
- title: Not specified

Could someone explain the context of the 'From' label.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s referring to an [HTML label](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-label-element) tag.

```
<label for=“answer”>Answer</label>
<input id=“answer”>
```

This is the “right” way to mark up a label for a form field.

- aria-labelledby is a work-around when the label can’t be marked up by a label tag (e.g. see [this recent answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/100573/61))
- aria-label is an alternative when for whatever reason there isn’t a tag whose content identifies the label
- the others are not intended to be used as labels, but assistive technologies sometimes use them as fallbacks

Comment: Ahh thanks. I did not think to associate From with the <label for or the implicitly wrapped <label. The FROM threw me.  Accessible name FROM the label! Of course makes sense.